# What is the purpose of `Intersect({}, ....`

Tags: mdx

I've seen this used inside `GENERATE` functions and wonder what the purpose of it is?

```
Intersect({}, ....
```

It is the intersection of the empty set `{}` with another set. Via set theory I know that the intersection of the empty set with *any* other set is equal to an empty set.

Chris Webb uses this construct quite regularly (part of a complex query [HERE](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2007/06/25/advanced-ranking-and-dynamically-generated-named-sets-in-mdx/)) but I'm a little unsure of the reason as it is used within more advanced queries - can someone explain with some simple examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is intentionally having the intersect expression return an empty set since Intersect({},anything) will return an empty set. But notice the `AS EmployeeSet` clause inside the Intersect. That's the point. That generates a named set with the name EmployeeSetXXX. The StrToSet function is what lets you name that set something different per month.

Anyway you have correctly understood how Intersect works. Chris is using it in a novel way.

Comment: thanks Greg - will the named set also have the correct dimensionality - even though it is empty, or can anything get added to it?

Comment: Yes. Because the named sets are aliases of the second parameter of Intersect. So it aliases it before Intersect make it empty.

Comment: @whytheq are you pretty clear what Intersect is doing now?

Comment: was the question interesting?